# NPoco plain SQL request with table, column name substituted from database mapping?

Tags: sql, orm, npoco

suppose I have my data class

```
[TableName("some_table")]
public class MyData 
{
 [ColumnName("some_column") 
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to execute a plain SQL query against my table, but I don't want to hardcode table/column name in my query. 
E.g. "update some_table set some_column = replace(some_column, '...', '...')" is bad because table, column name are hardcoded into the request.
I would prefer something like "update {{ MyData }} set {{ Name }} = ...", where {{ MyData }} {{ Name }} would be replaced by table, column name from NPoco database mapping.
Is it possible to retrieve this info from NPoco database?

Answer (score 2):

I finally came up with these extension methods that retrieve table name from type and column name for property:

```
public static class NPOCOExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableNameFromType<T>(this Database db)
    {
        return db.PocoDataFactory.TableInfoForType(typeof(T)).TableName;
    }

    public static string GetColumnNameFromProperty<T>(this Database db, Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
    {
        var memberName = ((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member.Name;
        var columnName = db.PocoDataFactory.ForType(typeof(T)).Members.Where(x => x.Name == memberName).First().PocoColumn.ColumnName;
        return columnName;
    }
}
```